# Hibernate Self Join Many to Many Mapping using self set of id's

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I'm trying to create a new hibernate self many-to-many mapping using a set of Long Id's (self id's) what is the correct mapping for it?

I trying to create a mapping between Person and his friends(Persons off course)
I have a Person class map to a tbl_person table.

**Person.java**

```
public class Person {
    private Long personId;
    private String name;
    //much more properties in here make this object huge
    private Set<Person> friends= new HashSet<Person>();
}
```

hibernate **Person.hbm.xml** mapping:

```
<set name="friends" table="friends" cascade="none" lazy="false">
    <key column="friend_id"/>
    <many-to-many column="person_id" class="com.kruders.model.bean.Person"/>
</set>
```

consider Person class extremely big.
Instead of doing:

```
    Set<Person> friends
```

I want to use a set of Person Ids:

```
    Set<Long> friendsIds
```

this way I won't be able to hold the entire Person object(again, very big) in memory.

hibernate xml mapping:

Expected results is a mapping table personId (foreign key to tbl_person) to friend (foreign key to tbl_person)
The id of that table is a composite of both columns.

tbl_friends

```
personId|friend
1       |2
1       |3
2       |1
```

Thank you.

Comment: why don't you use lazy true?

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I will use lazy='true' but do you know how the correct mapping should be look like?

Comment: There is no way in my knowledge that keep only ids through mapping physically only id is stored but it referes to whole object